# PHP MySQL delete where values are equal to

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP chat script that calls a MySQL database when a user signs out to delete them from the database.

My script is:

```
  if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE username='" .$user['username']. "' AND rank='0'");
    header("Location: login_mini.php?logout=1");
  }
```

What I want to do is delete the user if they have a rank of 0 when they leave. Why isn't this script working?

Comment: Echo your query, then try directly inputting the query into MySQL.

Comment: If you're trying to reference a value from an array it should be `username='{$user['username']}'`. Note the curly brackets and the quotes around the key.

Comment: watch out for SQL injection with any of the answers so far

Comment: You said `What I want to do is delete anyone with the rank of 0 when they leave` which means you don't need to add `username` in WHERE statement , `rank=0` is enough.. your statement is very conflicting with your SQL statement that you want. Just my opinion

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox I just tried that and any entry is still deleted when the script is executed even if rank=4. Any ideas?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Noted. I just changed that.

Comment: Actually...wait a minute. How is the query even successfully running? `DELETE * FROM` is not valid as far as I know; it should just be `DELETE FROM`.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox I think it is valid, just tried both and still not working though.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña won't it delete all users with `rank=0`? I think the OP wants to delete only a specific user with `rank=0`

Comment: @user2036031, really? have you tried running the query in phpmyadmin? Just run `DELETE * FROM users WHERE username='myusername' AND rank='0'`

Comment: @blo he have updated his question :)

Comment: It sounds like either there's something you're leaving out here (or just missing), or there's something very strange going on with your MySQL installation. This is a very basic, straightforward query and it doesn't make sense that it would be deleting rows that don't match.

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: If someone puts in a username of `' OR 1=1; --` then you will delete every user.

Answer (score 2):

DELETE doesn't take column arguments

Remove the *

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for MYSQL Delete example:

```
DELETE FROM somelog WHERE user = 'jcole'
ORDER BY timestamp_column LIMIT 1;
```

So you're query is wrong that's the reason why it is not running:

It should be

```
//without * and add quotes in your $user['username']
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE username=" .$user['username']. " AND rank='0'");
```

Comment: +1 This is mostly a consolidation of all the comments but it's also the only complete and correct answer.

Comment: @user2036031 , have you tried running the query in mysql? if it's not running then my suggestion is to put the rest of your code.

Comment: Have it `echo` the query: `"DELETE FROM users WHERE username='" .$user['username']. "' AND rank='0'"`. Connect to the database directly and paste that exact string. What happens?

Comment: Also, @DrixsonOseña, it looks like you removed the single quotes from the query on your edit - those should be in there since the column is presumably a varchar or other string type.

Comment: @user2036031 - `echo "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='" .$user['username']. "' AND rank='0'"` prints `1`?

Comment: Then I'm kind of at a loss. It sounds like there's a problem with your PHP installation if `echo` isn't even behaving the way it's supposed to. Even if `$user` was null, it should just output `username=''` along with the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE username='$user[username]' AND rank=0");
```

There is no * or any columns in DELETE operation because you are deleting the whole row(s).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that users table have a record that have rank == 0 ?
Check it by

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM users
WHERE rank='0'
```

then if there is check your variable $user['username'] if it has value.

```
var_dump($user);
```

then if both has value then try to execute this manually on your mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE username = #the value of the username
    AND rank = '0'
```

If there is a result then maybe your PHP is throwing an error while executing the mysql_query. try to insert this code after the mysql_query

```
if (mysql_error()) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: by the way for security reason enclosed your $user['username'] with mysql_real_escape(). this to protect your query from SQL Injection.